# javascript iframe play video

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I need a suggestion

On my page, I need to have an iframe with video.
My question how can I detect mouse click if their person clicks on the play and open a popup with a form before the video play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach onclick event on video tag.